# for, while and repeated loops to find averages of a column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop, average

My goal is to find the average of purchase amount using a for loop, a while loop and a repeated loop. This will help me to understand the functionality and use of each of the different loops.

```
1    {DATE} {Purchase amount} {ITEMS}
2    2018        682.23        cheese 
3    2017        752.25        cheese 
7891 2001        6584.98       cheese
```

Comment: hey in which lang do you need the ans and the column you provided is it any data type or some file containing these content ?

Comment: Typically in R you would just use `mean(YOUR_TABLE$Purchase_amount`).

Comment: @AshutoshAnand there isnt a file this is just for an example, just trying to see the formats for the loops for this particular problem, the coding language is R. Thank you so much for the questions and i look forward to your response!

Comment: @JonSpring thank you for that information, for this I am trying to see the functionality of the loops using averages, I believe there is some benefit I can gain from doing it through one of the 3 loops. I appreciate the comment and the code you provided, this will be very useful to me later down the road!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for informing us of your goal. Now, please share what you have tried and ask a *specific* question about the issues you face (i.e., errors, undesired results) with a [mcve]. If needed, please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) for how to do this in R and then give it an earnest try. Good luck!

Comment: @Parfait i have honestly no clue how to find an average using the mentioned loops which is why i am asking for such broad help, learning code for me is extremely difficult and for the most part im brute forcing my way through to try to understand until something clicks. I know it sounds weird or sort of inefficient but this is how i genuinely learn, reading on the subject wont do me much good as i have tried that on several occasions.

Answer (score 0):

For average in R there's an inbuilt function **mean** `mean(data)` you can use that ..
for eg if you have an list or 2 dimensional Array of int and want the mean data of that:-

[image]

**OUTPUT:-**

[image]

***HOPE IT HELP!!***

Comment: this does help my learning but unfortunately not for the question though I do appreciate the help, what i am trying to see is what the code would look like to find the averages using the different loops.

Comment: Ohk. You need the average using loop not the big deal.. Sorry for my bad i will rectify my answer tommorow..

Comment: No problem, take your time, i appreciate the help and any pointers you are able to provide for me